# Kerberos and Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, kerberos

I have been reading through past posts but I am still getting issues with 2 SQL servers connecting using a linked server when querying from a 3rd SQL server.  I constantly get the error "Login failed for user NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS"

I have set the SPNs correctly using the Kerberos Configuration Manager provided by Microsoft for the service account SQL is running as on each machine.  I have also been reading that if the computer contains a linked server then the computer object in AD needs trusting for delegation is that correct?  Also do the service accounts need trusting for delegation?

I can't just make the changes to test so I need to get this right beforehand.

Comment: Yes, the computer and service accounts must be able to delegate, without that right, active directory doesn't trust them to present accounts for validation.

Comment: I had this problem too but didn't find the solution. I bypassed it by using SQL authentication instead. This works like a charm.

Comment: OK I will get the delegation added and see how it goes.

Comment: I have go the service account and computer objects changed to Trust this user for delegation to any Service (Kerberos only) and I still get the failed Anonymous Login problem.